# IntelliJ "Can't find" Movie File

Tags: intellij-idea, movieclip, movie

I am having serious trouble opening, actually finding, any kind of Video Files with IntelliJ.

The files are in a folder called "data" in my Project Directory. In the Project Structure Settings I made sure the Folder is recognized as Source. Then I even declared my *.mov & *.mp4 files as new Filetypes.

But still when I am trying to load the video like:

```
mov = new GSMovie(p, "camel.mov"); or even

mov = new GSMovie(p, "data/camel.mov");
```

It doesn't find it.

I also tried different libarays.
and keep getting:

```
File camel.mov does not exist. Please check location.
```

Actually I just found out that it is looking in the IDEA app binary itself.

The JMC-Video for Processing:

Media unavailable: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2010%20CE.app/bin/data/look321.mp4

It works if I copy my files now there, but this can't be right.

It feels like I am doing something fundamentaly wrong, but I just can't see it.
thanx, for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `*.mp4` and `*.mov` to `Settings|Compiler|Resource Patterns`

Comment: Thanx this helped already a bit! Now it finds my .svg like it's supposed too. still doesn't find the *.mov & *.mp4 so the problem is nailed down to the JMCVideo library.

Comment: Check the library documentation, it may load files from path or from the classpath resource. If the first, copying to output will not help as the library expects file path.

Answer (score 0):

Set the working directory to the project root in the Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: the wierd thing is it is already set there in Configuration / Default / Application / Workingdirctory. Could it be, that the library itself doesn't know where to look?

Comment: Yes, it could be that the library ignores the current working directory, however it's weird that the path is appended to IDEA working directory, it looks like your setting doesn't have any effect.